# crontab and DST disagreement with different timezone

Tags: cron, timezone

From a server hosted in Poland (UTC +01:00), is there a way I can consistently have a crontab entry run at 9am New York time (UTC -05:00)?

For me this wasn't trivial since the daylight saving time ended last Sunday in Poland, so jobs that I have scheduled to run at 15:00 their local time most of the year are late this week by an hour from the point of view of US stock exchanges.

I remember Congress' decision a few years ago to extend DST, which put things out of sync for a few weeks per year.

One workaround I am not even sure would work (which I prefer to avoid anyhow) is that when I have a task:

```
0 14 * * * something
```

I fetch NY's time `TZ=":US/Eastern" date +%s` and compare using bash arithmetic whether I should `sleep 3600` or not before running `something`

Comment: Hmmm, you could pass the TZ environment variable to cron in its init.d script (`TZ=':America/New_York'`) to have *all* your cron jobs run in New York time. BTW: New York is currently on DST, and is thus UTC-0400.

Comment: No; I don't want all, and according to some other posts, TZ doesn't necessarily affect crontab (in Ubuntu which I use it doesn't), unlike for `date` eg. `TZ=":US/Eastern" date +%Y%m%d`

Comment: Minor update. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database implies that since the DST rules for each zone are published into the TZ database, any up-to-date UNIX server should already have bundled knowledge of the wall clock time anywhere else in the world without having to consult over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since altering the TZ env for `date` does seem to call up the correct current time in Ubuntu, this is at least a workaround (the one I was trying not to rely on):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

0 14 * * 1-5  [ $[10#$(date +\%H) - 10#$(TZ=":US/Eastern" date +\%H)] == 5 ] || sleep 3600; w;df
```

So this aims to run `w;df` at 9am ET Mon-Fri. Instead of hour 15 I put in 14 with the possibility of sleeping one hour (3600 seconds) before running further commands.

Comment: I don't like that 1. this isn't a host-timezone-indifferent solution, and 2. assumes the difference will never be greater than six hours, i.e., that DST in Poland will always end first and start last.

Comment: In some cases got `/bin/bash: 15 - 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")`
due to subtle problem of bash treatment of numbers beginning with 0 as octal.  Fixed by preceding 10# to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If its only one job, you can use a kluge like this:

```
# MM HH        DM MN DW   CMD
  0  *         *  *  *    TZ=':America/New_York'; if [ `date +\%H` -eq 9 ]; then actual-command-here; fi
```

I think you can set the environment variable like that in a crontab, if not just put the whole thing in a `sh -c` or a shell script...

I have a cron job that I need to run every other week which I use a similar kluge for.

Comment: Thanks for the kluge; 9am was only a simplified example, in reality I have tasks sprinkled all over the clock and calendar.  Developing on your idea, rather than stuffing my much longer, nastier crontab line into an `if` block, I could merely precede my commands with: ` [ $[$(date +%H) - $(TZ=":US/Eastern" date +%H)] == 5 ] && sleep 3600; w` where `w` is what I want to run at the right time

Comment: `sleep 3600` is only if you can only ever come in one hour early. What about when DST starts (Spring, instead of fall?)

Comment: The idea is that for most of the year, a 1-hour wait will not be in effect. Only during the few weeks of a 5-hour difference (whether spring or fall), rather than the typical 6, will sleep 3600 be executed.

Comment: Um, the opposite of what I last wrote.